# Filebeat: Certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

I am getting this error from filebeat:

> Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://elk.example.com:9200)): Get https://elk.example.com:9200: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
>
> INFO    pipeline/output.go:93   Attempting to reconnect to backoff(elasticsearch(https://elk.example.com:9200)) with 1468 reconnect attempt(s)
>
> INFO    [publish]       pipeline/retry.go:189   retryer: send unwait-signal to consumer
>
> INFO    [publish]       pipeline/retry.go:191     done
>
> INFO    [publish]       pipeline/retry.go:166   retryer: send wait signal to consumer
>
> INFO    [publish]       pipeline/retry.go:168     done

However, elasticsearch is having valid SSL by letsencrypt. (This is not a self-signed certificate).

Filebeat kubernetes config:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
  username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
  password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
```

I tried adding these parameters in config file and it worked. But, why do I need to bypass verification even if certificate is valid.

```
ssl.verification_mode: "none"
```

Comment: I'm assuming your actual domain is not `example.com`? Does your elasticsearch container have a proper list of trusted root CAs? What image is it based on?

Comment: @johnharris85: Correct. Actual URL is different. I am using open distro. https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/install/ . When I open elasticsearch URL in browser I can see it valid certificate with Letsencrypt Authority. No warning message.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote elasticsearch when I meant filebeat before. Does your `filebeat` container have the right root CAs? Also from your filebeat container can you grab the cert and inspect it using openssl to make sure you're getting the right one?

Comment: @johnharris85: Filebeat doesn't have ssl configuration. I am using this config file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/7.0/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml

Comment: *even if certificate is valid* you don't need to bypass verification mode if the certificate is valid, you need to teach the container about the certificate roots that **you** consider valid; most of them have out-of-date CA chains, which often don't include things like Let's Encrypt roots. So I in principle agree with you: don't switch off SSL verification, update the CA list in the container to be correct

Comment: I found this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/configuration-ssl.html. I am not specifying any of these settings in filebeat config file. I generated certificate using letsencrypt in elasticsearch server. It didn't generate any client side certificates which I can use it in filebeat. Should I just use `chain.pem` in `output.elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authorities` field?

Comment: @RonakPatel I'm facing the exact same issue right now. My filebeat is unable to trust the cert for Elasticsearch that has been issued by Letsecrypt..what was your solution at the end? did you update the list of trusted CAs on your filebeat image?

Comment: In my case, I had to set the full chain of the certificate for the TLS config

Answer (score 2):

The reason is either an old default operating system truststore that does not feature your very much valid and well-known trusted CA chains or the Elasticsearch certificate is self-signed or signed by a private CA.

You can choose from a number of solutions:

1. Run your filebeat in an environment (server, container, etc) with an updated default truststore that knows the CA that signed your certificate - i.e: upgrade to a newer version of the operating system or updated container image.
2. Remove your `ssl.verification_mode: "none"` configuration and add a `ssl.certificate_authorities` point to one or more PEM files with the to-be trusted CA certificates.

> ```
>  output.elasticsearch:
>    hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
>    username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
>    password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
>    ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/path/to/ca.pem"]
> ```

3. Remove your `ssl.verification_mode: "none"` configuration and add a `ssl.certificate_authorities` configuration with the embedded to-be trusted CA certificate directly in the YAML configuration.

Example from [filebeat configuration documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/configuration-ssl.html).

> ```
> certificate_authorities:
>   - |
>     -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>     MIIDCjCCAfKgAwIBAgITJ706Mu2wJlKckpIvkWxEHvEyijANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
>     ADAUMRIwEAYDVQQDDAlsb2NhbGhvc3QwIBcNMTkwNzIyMTkyOTA0WhgPMjExOTA2
>     MjgxOTI5MDRaMBQxEjAQBgNVBAMMCWxvY2FsaG9zdDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
>     BQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBANce58Y/JykI58iyOXpxGfw0/gMvF0hUQAcUrSMxEO6n
>     fZRA49b4OV4SwWmA3395uL2eB2NB8y8qdQ9muXUdPBWE4l9rMZ6gmfu90N5B5uEl
>     94NcfBfYOKi1fJQ9i7WKhTjlRkMCgBkWPkUokvBZFRt8RtF7zI77BSEorHGQCk9t
>     /D7BS0GJyfVEhftbWcFEAG3VRcoMhF7kUzYwp+qESoriFRYLeDWv68ZOvG7eoWnP
>     PsvZStEVEimjvK5NSESEQa9xWyJOmlOKXhkdymtcUd/nXnx6UTCFgnkgzSdTWV41
>     CI6B6aJ9svCTI2QuoIq2HxX/ix7OvW1huVmcyHVxyUECAwEAAaNTMFEwHQYDVR0O
>     BBYEFPwN1OceFGm9v6ux8G+DZ3TUDYxqMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFPwN1OceFGm9v6ux
>     8G+DZ3TUDYxqMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAG5D
>     874A4YI7YUwOVsVAdbWtgp1d0zKcPRR+r2OdSbTAV5/gcS3jgBJ3i1BN34JuDVFw
>     3DeJSYT3nxy2Y56lLnxDeF8CUTUtVQx3CuGkRg1ouGAHpO/6OqOhwLLorEmxi7tA
>     H2O8mtT0poX5AnOAhzVy7QW0D/k4WaoLyckM5hUa6RtvgvLxOwA0U+VGurCDoctu
>     8F4QOgTAWyh8EZIwaKCliFRSynDpv3JTUwtfZkxo6K6nce1RhCWFAsMvDZL8Dgc0
>     yvgJ38BRsFOtkRuAGSf6ZUwTO8JJRRIFnpUzXflAnGivK9M13D5GEQMmIl6U9Pvk
>     sxSmbIUfc2SGJGCJD4I=
>     -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> ```

**Disclaimer**: You have not provided a filebeat version so I assumed the latest one. Nevertheless, this kind of configuration will probably be the same across filebeat versions.